# My Unwrapped Baked texture is mostly bugged

Tags: texture-baking, baking

[image]

As you can see from this image, every time I try and bake the diffuse for this object, with the indirect and direct influence turned off, the results turn out to be this weird mess of a texture file.

Haven't encountered this problem before and I tried several solutions like uv unwrapping again, chaging the normals, checking if the correct image file is selected in the node editor etc.

Here's the .blend file if it helps in any way.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OW6g5rU7EVIK8NZCmWU3AzuB9YSacIdy

Comment: Hi and welcome to Blender Stackexchange. Please use [blend-exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) to upload .blend files. Files on other services tend to "vanish", thus rendering your question and possible answers practically useless in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is correct, but before baking you have to make sure you need to create a new image say "untitled.png" in "UV Editor" to bake and add image texture to all the material files that the object have.

In your case you have 2 materials i.e. green one, and yellow one.

Add Image texture with the created image "untitled.png" selected in both the materials and bake diffuse texture with just "color" selected.

Solution gif file --> [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zG0sK.jpg) (its over 12mb but 2mb limit. so can't upload directly)

Follow the gif file and

After the baking completes you'll have something like this. Just need to save this to local disk.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that, I totally forgot to add and select an image texture for the second material, that may have been my problem.
Really appreciate your help.